# gnuplot wont process my script for a simple sum of exponential

Tags: gnuplot

Can anyone tell me why i won't get any output if i try to process this `tuneliranje_1.gp` file with gnuplot:

```
set terminal epslatex color colortext size 9cm,5cm
set size 1.5,1.0
set output "tuneliranje_1.tex"

set style line 1 linetype 1 linewidth 3 linecolor rgb "#FF0055"

set grid

set key at graph 1, 0.95
set key samplen 2
set key spacing 2

f(x)=30*exp(2*x)+3*exp(-2*x)

set xtics ("$0$" 0)
set ytics ("$0$" 0)

set xrange [-11:10]
set yrange [-0.5:3]

plot f(x) ls 1 title "$f(x)=30 e^{2x}+3e^{-2x}$"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say because the minimum value of that function in the range you specified is around 18.. Try putting `set yrange[0:100]`

Comment: I better not say a thing... I am a noob from time to time. I thought a problem was in a program but it was in MY mathematics hehe. Thank you.

Comment: Those things happen to all of us :)
Bye